# Microservice Two-Phase Commit: Transaction coordinator is down in the middle of process

Tags: microservices, transaction

I've just read this article, about [handling distributed transactions in the microservices world](https://medium.com/swlh/handling-transactions-in-the-microservice-world-c77b275813e0).

In the article, the author explained two possible solutions available.

I'm familiar with SAGA. But never actually tried the **Two-Phase Commit** pattern.

And here we go with my question:

In the **Two-Phase Commit** pattern, how to handle data inconsistency if suddenly in the middle of the process, the transaction coordinator service is down? If it happens in the middle of the process, some data on certain services may be updated already.

Comment: Did you mean the "transaction coordinator?"

Comment: yes. let me update it to make it clear

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for possible failures, you *will* find some. According to the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) distributed transactions can not be 100% safe, not in the "database" isolation-level-atomicity sense.

In a distributed system you'll always have to have some compromise. This is why distributed transactions are usually regarded as an anti-pattern in a microservices environment. First, it can not be done (with 100 percent reliability). Second, it makes things unnecessarily complex.

Usually it is better to design your way around the need for distributed transactions by properly choosing where certain functionalities are, or ordering steps in some way, etc.